# Openfiledailog box without using Microsoft.Win32

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm

I am using openfiledailog box using ike this but i want to do same functionality without using Microsoft.Win32 refrence

```
  Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
  dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
  dlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
  //Nullable<bool> result =
  dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: @RezaAghaei WPF in MVVM pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can create your own dialog that shows list of files and let the user select file.

**Option 2**

You can use [`GetOpenFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) instead:

```
[DllImport("comdlg32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool GetOpenFileName([In, Out] OpenFileName ofn);
```

And here is [pinvoke.net page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comdlg32.getopenfilename).

Here is a working sample of what you need:

```
[DllImport("comdlg32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool GetOpenFileName([In, Out] OpenFileName ofn);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class OpenFileName
{
    public int structSize = 0;
    public IntPtr dlgOwner = IntPtr.Zero;
    public IntPtr instance = IntPtr.Zero;
    public String filter = null;
    public String customFilter = null;
    public int maxCustFilter = 0;
    public int filterIndex = 0;
    public String file = null;
    public int maxFile = 0;
    public String fileTitle = null;
    public int maxFileTitle = 0;
    public String initialDir = null;
    public String title = null;
    public int flags = 0;
    public short fileOffset = 0;
    public short fileExtension = 0;
    public String defExt = null;
    public IntPtr custData = IntPtr.Zero;
    public IntPtr hook = IntPtr.Zero;
    public String templateName = null;
    public IntPtr reservedPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    public int reservedInt = 0;
    public int flagsEx = 0;
}

private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileName openFileName = new OpenFileName();
    openFileName.structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(openFileName);
    openFileName.filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)\0*.jpeg\0PNG Files (*.png)\0*.png\0JPG Files (*.jpg)\0*.jpg\0GIF Files (*.gif)\0*.gif\0";
    openFileName.file = new String(new char[256]);
    openFileName.maxFile = openFileName.file.Length;
    openFileName.fileTitle = new String(new char[64]);
    openFileName.maxFileTitle = openFileName.fileTitle.Length;
    openFileName.title = "Open";
    openFileName.defExt = "png";

    if (GetOpenFileName(openFileName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(openFileName.file);
    }
}
```

Based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) and [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comdlg32.getopenfilename) and [Arie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891715/arie) Code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion But is there any way without importing DLL

Comment: @Rahul As an alternative, You can create your own dialog, like any other dialog.